# I can't activate mariadb cluster node

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, galera

I was installing and configuring the first mariadb 1.0.33 cluster node in fedora 27 from scratch. I did the following steps:

1. $setenforce 0
2. $yum -y install MariaDB-Galera-server MariaDB-client rsync galera
3. $mysql -u root

   ```
   MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'cluster1-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'cluster1-user' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   MariaDB [(none)]> exit;
   ```
4. $service mysql stop
5. $vim /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf

   ```
   [mariadb-10.0]
   query_cache_size=0
   binlog_format=ROW
   default_storage_engine=innodb
   innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
   wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
   wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.56.104"
   wsrep_cluster_name='cluster1'
   wsrep_node_address='192.168.56.104'
   wsrep_node_name='galera-db01'
   wsrep_sst_method=rsync
   ```
6. $service mysql bootstrap //mariadb starts with success
7. $mysql -u root -p -e "show status like 'wsrep%'"

Even though the output is

```
Variable              Value
---------------------------------
wsrep_cluster_size     0
wsrep_cluster_status   disconected
wsrep_connected        OFF
wsrep_provider_name    
wsrep_ready            ON
wsrep_thread_count      0
```

My question is why it shows me disconected, cluster size=0. What is missing?

Regards

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Better yet, dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Fedora 27 the default MariaDB version is 10.2.9 at the moment. So cluster settings under a mariadb-10.0 section in server.cnf won't be read, which would explain lack of cluster success.

Comment: It was helpful. I reinstalled to fedora 23 with MariaDB 10.1 series